# Check which subclass an object is in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, struct, subclass

Given that there are the following struct types:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};
struct D : B {};
```

And we have a piece of code:

```
A a = f();
```

How would you check what type the struct actually is? i.e. is it `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`?

I can give the context in which I'm trying to use the answer for this if needed, but I don't think that's needed.

Comment: It probably is needed (how do we know a virtual function won't solve your problem) and the type is clearly `A`, always, since any derived type returned would be sliced.

Answer (score 2):

Note that polimorphism in C++ only works with pointers and references, if you return A by value, it will always be an A. If the function f() returns a class of type B, [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) will occur.

If you change the function to return a pointer to A, then you can use a dynamic cast and check if returns null.

```
A *a=f();
B *b=dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
if(b!=NULL)
{
    //a was of type B
}
```

Comment: My question was less regarding how we're obtaining `a`, more how do we check if it's actually something else (e.g. `B`). The `dynamic_cast` approach works. Thanks :)

Comment: Keep in mind that if you happen to do the same with references instead of pointers, `dynamic_cast` throws an exception of type `bad_cast` if the type doesn't match (as null references don't exist in C++).

Comment: @user2671945 And sometimes, an exception is exactly what you need. :-)

Comment: I wasn't implying anything negative with the exception behaviour. You just have to be aware of that, and remeber a `try..catch` block around a `dynamic_cast` among references when you're unsure if it'll succeed, just as the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

It's type `A`. Why? Because of slicing.

If, however, `f()` returned an `A&`, and you used `A& a = f();` instead, then you have two options (both involving RTTI):

1. You could use `typeid(a)` and either look at its `name()` or compare against the `type_info` objects for the various (sub)classes.
2. You could use a `dynamic_cast`: for example, `dynamic_cast<D*>(&a)` would return null if `a` is not of type `D`.

Comment: Given something along the lines of `A f() { B b; return b; }`, it's of type B.

EDIT: Also, this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @BertieWheen no, it is `A` *and only* `A`. That is, assuming OP wants to know the type of variable `a`.

Comment: @BertieWheen `A f() {B b; return b;}` always returns an object of type `A` because of slicing. But if you had something like `A* f() {return new B;}`, then the returned pointer would indeed reference an object of type `B`.

Comment: return new Something is a no no

Comment: @DieterLücking, how would you write the function? I know return new something isn't good, but I'm not sure about the best practice alternative

Comment: @DieterLücking It's not a no-no if the return type is `unique_ptr<A>` ;-), but in any case, I was simply trying to talk about how the main way to avoid slicing is to return by pointer/reference (and I didn't want to create a dangling reference).

Comment: @BertieWheen Return a `unique_ptr` or a `shared_ptr`, depending on what ownership model you need.

Comment: What BertieWheen says